# What wiki engines have strong MVC separation?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, wiki

I would like use an existing wiki engine but replace the render and editing functions of the wiki with client-side javascript. Modifying HTML already rendered by the server application with Jquery or the likes in not a viable option because some critical features I intend to write don't seem like they would be straightforward to implement with that method but I could be wrong. Some features:

- lazy-load additional wiki pages
- switch on the fly between editing and viewing the wiki without reloading
- render wiki mark-up without reloading
- Possibly create new wiki pages and start editing without reloading

Maybe I am going at this the wrong way and if so feel free to comment on that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever I wonder "What wiki engines has both  and ",
I go to http://www.wikimatrix.org/ and hit the "Wiki Choice Wizard" and see what wiki engines it "recommends".
That narrows down the choices down to the best candidates much faster than manually going through [the list of wiki engines at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wiki_software).

In particular, the wiki matrix makes it easy to narrow "the list of all wiki that it knows about" to just "the wiki written in languages you are comfortable using".

There has been some discussion of client-side rendering using Javascript; see

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TiddlyWiki
- http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FilesystemBasedWiki
- http://features.sheep.art.pl/JavascriptParser